# display data on selecting values from Dropdown without page refresh or button click using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have  a drop down on php form,  I want to populate guest names in it, which has been done, now I want to load data from table on the basis of value from this drop down and without page refresh/ button submission. How do I do this? I want simple code that could achieve it in one page rather than doing it through multiple pages. The examples I have seen so far are too complicated and when I merge them in my code, they no longer work.
Here is the function which im using onchange of dropdown:

```
    $("#guestname").change(function()
     {              
      var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();

      var dataString = 'action='+ id;
      $.ajax
      ({
        url: 'billing.php',
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(r)
        {
            $("#display").html(r);
        } 
      });
  })
```

Here is my billing.php code, it loads values on the basis of first selected value, if I again select value from drop down,it  doesn't show the updated record.

```
<?php
 include('config.php');
 $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
 $stmt=$dbcon->prepare('SELECT discount FROM table_name WHERE name=:name 
 ORDER BY name');
 $stmt->execute(array(':name'=>$action));
 }
 ?>
 <div class="row">
 <?php
 if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
 while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
 extract($row);
 ?>
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for javaScript

Comment: You need JavaScript and AJAX. Beyond that we can't help because we don't know anything specific about your existing code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without page refresh but you gonna need another php file, let's name it query.php to get you the result.

On your current page

```
<select>
    <option value='bob'>Bob
    <option value='jane'>Jane
</select>

<div id='output'></div>

<script>
$('select').change(function(){
    let name = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'query.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {username: name},
        success: function(response){
            $('#output').html(response);
        }
    });
})
```

In query.php

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
//query database to get your result
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: You might want to note that this requires jQuery and that there are other ways of sending an AJAX request which don't require extra libraries